# Minimized Apps appear on Win7 Desktop instead of in the Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Until today when an application was minimized its icon was still on the Taskbar. To return focus to the program I would simply click the icon on the Taskbar.

Today, minimized applications now appear as minimized windows taking up desktop space. The Taskbar functionality has not changed. (See below.)

[image: screenshot of sample item]

Why are minimized apps now showing as a small window on the desktop? More importantly, how does one restore things where just the Taskbar icon represents the application?

Comment: What have you tried already to rectify it (reboots, System Restore, etc.)?  Have you done any customization to the shell using 3rd party utilities?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the window frame and manually selecting minimize just to see if that works?

Comment: I've not changed anything in attempt to fix, and a reboot will need to wait for some completed work first.

Right-clicking on the frame does not give me a pop-up menu. Left-click on the icon gives the standard pop-up and minimizes the same.

Comment: I have seen this behavior when `Explorer.exe` gets out of whack, I bet a restart will fix it too. If it persists after a reboot please update the question with that info.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. In reality, one should always reboot before posting problems on sites such as this. It appears a reboot fixed it. (It still seems very weird - a flashback to yesteryear....)

Comment: I had a similar issue and didn't want to reboot the machine. Restarting explorer.exe using the task manager worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem just now. I believe it is a disorder caused by explorer.exe. What I did to fix it without restarting the machine, is to kill (or end) the process "explorer.exe" in Task Manager, then re-run it again [File>New task (run..)]. 
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reboot, just restart the explorer.exe process

**taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe**       - your desktop will disappear

**explorer.exe**                       - your old desktop reappears!